# How to remove a td from tr on click of a button

Tags: jquery

When i click on the del button , the output i get is

```
$(document).on("click", ".deletevideo", function(event)
{
     var video_id = $(this).data('videoid');
    var html = $('#videosexistingtable tr[video-id="' + video_id + '"]').prop('outerHTML');
    console.log(html);
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
});
```

This is the current output

```
<tr class="existingvideos" video-id="110">
   <td>TCS</td>
   <td>Chandra</td>
   <td>
      <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-circle">IT</span> 
   </td>
   <td>
      <i class="fa fa-check">Banking</i>
   </td>
   <td><a data-videoid="110" class="fa fa-trash remove-delete-icon deletevideo ui-link" title="Delete">Del</a></td>
</tr>
```

Is it possible to remove this td completely

```
   <td><a data-videoid="110" class="fa fa-trash remove-delete-icon deletevideo ui-link" title="Delete">Del</a></td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/351/

Comment: Do you want to remove td having del link on click of it? Or you want to remove the tr?

Comment: what he asks for in the last snip is to literally delete the delete button

Comment: I want to remove the td having del link

Comment: As usual, your question is quite unclear and doesn't show any effort to resolve it. Again, SO isn't a free coding web service. Tell it to your boss!

Comment: To remove the td having del link you just have to place $(this).remove(); inside the click event.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to remove the whole row? (tr) then try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".deletevideo", function(event){
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable2 table table-bordered table-hover" id="videosexistingtable">
   <tbody class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
      <tr class="existingvideos">
         <th>Comp Name</th>
         <th>CEO</th>
         <th>Industry</th>
         <th>Domains</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="existingvideos" video-id="110">
         <td>TCS</td>
         <td>Chandra</td>
         <td>
            <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-circle">IT</span> 
         </td>
         <td>
            <i class="fa fa-check">Banking</i>
         </td>
         <td><a data-videoid="110" class="fa fa-trash remove-delete-icon deletevideo" title="Delete">Del</a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

If you just want to remove the td-cell you can change closest("tr") to closest("td")

Answer (score 1):

Place `$(this).remove();` inside click event to remove link from `td` having delete link.

Please check below working snippet.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".deletevideo", function(event){
  var video_id = $(this).data('videoid');
  var html = $('#videosexistingtable tr[video-id="' + video_id + '"]').prop('outerHTML');
  console.log(html);
  $(this).remove();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable2 table table-bordered table-hover" id="videosexistingtable">
  <tbody class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
    <tr class="existingvideos">
      <th>Comp Name</th>
      <th>CEO</th>
      <th>Industry</th>
      <th>Domains</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="existingvideos" video-id="110">
      <td>TCS</td>
      <td>Chandra</td>
      <td>
        <span class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-circle">IT</span> 
      </td>
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-check">Banking</i>
      </td>
      <td><a data-videoid="110" class="fa fa-trash remove-delete-icon deletevideo" title="Delete">Del</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this removes the anchor, not the `td`. But as usual OP didn't make any effort to understand code he will just copy/paste...

Answer (score 1):

This is the [updates](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/353/). See the class `.deleteThis`.

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/353/